# Swift - patch definition with selector using run-time arguments

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

I'm trying to create patcher for selector in assembly that uses run-time arguments feature but no luck. Has anyone solved similar issue or it can't be using Swift yet?

Method definition in assembly looks like this:

```
public dynamic func requestCodeApiGateway(phone: NSString) -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(RequestCodeApiGatewayImpl.self) { (definition) in
        definition.useInitializer("initWithApiService:apiRouter:phone:") { (initializer) in
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm creating Patcher like this:

```
let patcher = TyphoonPatcher()
patcher.patchDefinitionWithSelector("requestCodeApiGatewayWithPhone:") { 
    // ...
}
```

P.S. solutions with partially using Objective-C would be also appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong selector in `patchDefinitionWithSelector`.  With the exception of `init`, initial parameters aren't exposed as external parameter names and aren't included in selectors.

The selector for `requestCodeApiGateway(NSString)` is `requestCodeApiGateway:`.

Updating your code to use that selector should do the trick:

```
patcher.patchDefinitionWithSelector("requestCodeApiGateway:") { 
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can get the selector to be `requestCodeApiGatewayWithPhone:` any of the following ways:

1. Rename the method:

   ```
   public dynamic func requestCodeApiGatewayWithPhone(phone: NSString) -> AnyObject
   ```
2. Expose the external parameter name using longhand or shorthand notation:

   ```
   public dynamic func requestCodeApiGateway(phone phone: NSString) -> AnyObject
   public dynamic func requestCodeApiGateway(#phone: NSString) -> AnyObject
   ```
3. Override the selector registered with the Objective-C runtime:

   ```
   @objc(requestCodeApiGatewayWithPhone:)
   public dynamic func requestCodeApiGateway(phone: NSString) -> AnyObject
   ```

Options 1 and 2 will affect any Swift code calling that method and all methods will have the same effect on Objective-C code and the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: Thank's a lot!
I changed selector to "requestCodeApiGateway:" before, but must have messed up with all that cases i was trying to make it work. Now with fresh mind and your help it finally happened.